# grouping date in Highcharts if the date range is too big

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts to show some statistic for my customer but I have problem when the customer select long data range

here is the first image for my highchart in the default view [image]

and if I select too long date range here is the result 
[image]

here is my code

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 50,
                marginBottom: 80,
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },                  
            title: {
                text: 'Visits Statistics',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            credits: {
                text: '',
                href: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [<?php print $categories; ?>],
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    align: 'right',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '10px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Visits'
                },
                min: 0,
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +' '+'</b><br/>'+ this.y +'Hit';
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 10,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{name:'from 2011-09-1',data: [<?php print $visits; ?>]}]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  It looks like you are wanting to fix the x-axis label problem - that they overlap like crazy. Is that correct?

Comment: @ManiacalMonkey yes exactly .. I need it group it by months or weeks or years

Comment: Have you used a formatter for axes labels before?

Comment: You can try to use tickInterval parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickInterval

Answer (score 3):

Highcharts can automatically manage time values in the x-Axis, provided that your chart is configured correctly. The problem in your case is that you've told Highcharts to use your categories, and it shows *all* of the categories.

To set up your chart to avoid this, you'll need to do two things:

- Set the x-Axis type to `datetime`
- Make sure that your data is formatted correctly

  - Or, use `pointStart` and `pointInterval` if you can't mess around with the data.

Using your example:

```
// ...
xAxis: {
    //remove categories and set type as 'datetime'
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        rotation: -45,
        align: 'right',
        style: {
            fontSize: '10px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    }
},
// ...
series: [{
    name:'from 2011-09-1',
    // since you probably don't want to change your data, we leave it alone...
    data: [<?php print $visits; ?>],
    // ... and instead, set `pointStart` and `pointInterval`
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2011, 8, 1), // September 1, 2011
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // each point is 1 day (measured in milliseconds)
}]
```